# JavaScript Overall result based on score

Tags: javascript, widget, max

Currently I have a list of people and a list of shopping items mapped to each person. For example, Joe bought Apples and Grapes.

For me to get this data, each person has to go in and select whether they bought something. So I would ask the person "Did you buy something? (Apples, Grapes, etc)" and there is a Radio Button Option for "Yes", "No".

If Bob said "Yes" to Apples, but "No" to Grapes, I want an overall answer for Bob. The answer would be "Yes", since he did buy something.

So far I have this piece of code:

```
exports.getOverallAnswer = function(boughtSomething){
  var answer = ["Yes", "No"];
  var scores = [5,4];
  var highScore = Math.max.apply(Math,scores);
  var scoreIndex = scores.indexOf(highScore);
  var answerName = answer[scoreIndex];
  return answer;
  };
```

I'm having trouble tying this code to the apples and grapes values and each person. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally this is where boolean values would be very helpful here where they return either true or false.

You can have the person object with multiple checks.

For instance

```
Bob.boughtGrapes = false;
Bob.boughtApples = true;
```

Afterwards, you can have a function that checks whether a person object has bought something.

```
function boughtSomething(Person person) {
     $test = false;
     if (person.boughtGrapes === true)
          $test = true;
     if (person.boughtApple === true)
          $test = true;
     ......
     return $test;
}
```

edit:
Two other options related between choices. 
1) Number values:

```
Bob.boughtGrapes = 2;
//1 = "Yes" and 2 = "No" and 3 = "Maybe" and etc.
```

2) String values:

```
Bob.boughtGrapes = "Yes";
Bob.boughtApples = "No";
Bob.boughtPears = "Maybe";
```

The reason I'd advise against string values is because it is VERY easy to make a spelling error and spend a long time attempting to figure out why your program isn't working.

Now here is where you can decide whether or not maybe will trigger "Yes, this person has bought something."

```
 function boughtSomething(Person person) {
     $test = "No"; //Always start with a negative answer.
     if (person.boughtGrapes === "Yes" || person.boughtGrapes === "Maybe")
          $test = "Yes";
     if (person.boughtApples === "Yes" || person.boughtApples === "Maybe")
          $test = "Yes";
     ......
     return $test; //returns "Yes" on success, "No" otherwise.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Hypothetically, if I were to throw in another answer option i.e. Yes, No, and Maybe, the boolean approach would no longer work?